# Parse email and send reply using googleapiclient in Python

Tags: python, email, gmail, google-api-client

I'm currently working on a project and I have chosen to use Gmail for sending and receiving emails. I want to be able to send an email, have a user reply to it, and parse their response. The response can be any number of lines (so something like `response.split('\n')[0]` won't work). It should then be able to reply directly to that email thread.

I've been following the [googleapiclient tutorials](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python), but they leave a lot to be desired. However, I've managed to read email threads using:

```py
service.users.threads().get(userId='me', id=thread_id).execute()
```

where `thread_id` is (predictably) the ID of the email thread (which I find elsewhere). In the large dict returned by this, there is a section of base64 data which contains the content of the email. This was the only place I could find the actual data for the response. Unfortunately, I get this when it is decoded:

```py
b'This is my response from my phone\r\n\r\nOn Sat, 28 Nov 2020, 8:40 PM , <myemail@gmail.com>\r\nwrote:\r\n\r\n> This is sent from the python script\r\n>\r\n'
```

This is all the data in the thread, however, I only want the response as there is clearly no way to split this to get only the data I need. The best I can think of is to parse out anything of the form `On <date>, <time>`, but that could lead to problems. There must be another way to extract only `This is my response from my phone` and no other data.

---

Once I get the response, I want to parse it and reply with an appropriate response based on the contents of the message. I would prefer to **reply directly to the thread**, rather than starting a new one. Unfortunately, all the Google documentation says is:

> If you're trying to send a reply and want the email to thread, make sure that:
>
> 1. The Subject headers match
> 2. The References and In-Reply-To headers follow the RFC 2822 standard.

The documentation provides this code (with some minor modifications by me) for sending an email:

```py
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}
```

Sending a reply with the same subject line is pretty straight forward (`message['subject'] = same_subject_as_before`), but I don't even know where to start with the References and In-Reply-To headers. How do I set these?

Answer (score 3):

### Why is this hard?

You are trying to use e-mail for something it simply wasn't originally designed for. My impression is you want the e-mail response to contain structured data, but e-mail text lacks any well-defined structure. It also depends on which e-mail client the other user has, and whether they send HTML e-mail or not.

This is usually easy for a human to see, but difficult for a computer. Which suggests that Machine Learning might be the best strategy if you want higher reliability. Whatever solution you choose, it's not going to be 100% reliable.

- E-mail can be plain text or HTML, or both.
- There is no well-defined structure to separate replies from the original text. [Wikipedia lists a few different "posting styles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posting_style#Placement_of_replies).

  - In the old days when "Netiquette" was still cool, putting your reply on top ("top-posting") was considered bad practice, and new Internet users were told by old folks to avoid top-posting. Some users still reply below or interleaved with the original text.
- The reply line (e.g. "On DATE, EMAIL wrote:" or "-------- Original Message --------") will be different, depending on which e-mail client is used, what language that client is set to, and the user's own preferences.

### Using a text delimiter

A class of software which faces a similar problem as the one you describe is customer service applications, which allow operators to use e-mail for communication. A common strategy is to inject some unique text in your templates for outgoing e-mail. For example, [Zendesk uses a text "delimiter"](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015197788-Adding-and-removing-the-delimiter-from-email-notifications) such as:

> ##- Please type your reply above this line -##

This serves two purposes; it tells users to top-post, and it provides a separator to cut out most of the irrelevant text.

If you first handle any HTML encoding, you should be able to split the message by such a text delimiter. It's not perfect, but it usually works.

### Use products made by others

There are some open source options, such as:

- https://github.com/zapier/email-reply-parser

And I found a commercial product, SigParser, which seems to use a machine learning model that they've trained very carefully:

- https://sigparser.com/developers/extract-reply-chains-from-emails/

They also explain some of the challenges of parsing e-mail text into structured data.

Comment: Thanks @traal. I actually have an email from a company using Zendesk, but when in reply in Gmail, it turns into `On Sat, Nov 28, 2020 at 2:01 PM Person <person@email.com> wrote:
 ##- Please type your reply above this line -## The original email is here`. I still face the problem of needing to parse out the text at the top. Or would it be normal to just remove the line above to delimiter too?

Comment: @JolonB, you could try to do that, but it might fail if the other person doesn't use Gmail, and perhaps their e-mail client does something completely different. Provided that they have an empty line between their response and the original reply, you could try to remove the final paragraph above the delimiter. Especially if the final paragraph ends with a colon (:) or contains long sequences of dashes (----).